# MySQL upgrade causing unexpected results on simple WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm upgrading my Laravel app to use MySQL 8.0.23 from 8.0.20, and I see an issue with WHERE clauses that produce unexpected results.

```
SELECT * FROM guilds 
    WHERE platform_id = 1 
    AND platform_server_id = '407254666900930563';
```

Running ^ directly on the MySQL server produces the record I'm looking for (regardless of whether `40725...` is an `int` or a `string`). However, using it through Laravel's Eloquent Query Builder, it is not finding the record.  Here's the eloquent code.

```
// Won't find it if it's a string, will if it's an int
$serverId = '407254666900930563';
Server::where('platform_id', 1)
    ->where('platform_server_id', $serverId)
    ->first()
```

The data is here:

[image]

I've verified in the DB that `platform_id` does indeed = 1 (verified by running the SQL directly).

Here's my MySQL config on the Laravel side.

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
]) : [],
'modes'  => [
    /**
     * Disabled because of a group by we need
     */
    //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',

    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
]
```

I've looked through MySQL changelogs and am not seeing what could be causing this.  Does anyone have any ideas about what I should investigate?

CREATE TABLE statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE `guilds` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `platform_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `platform_server_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `guilds_platform_id_platform_server_id_unique` (`platform_id`,`platform_server_id`),
  KEY `guilds_platform_server_id_index` (`platform_server_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=691420 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: share the query and the exact error that you are facing

Comment: I did share the query, there's no error, it produces no records.

Comment: Do you get all attributes you expect when you dump the `Server` model? have you got any accessors/mutators there?

Comment: @Ballard Yes I do

Comment: have you tried this? `Server::where(['platform_id' => 1, 'platform_server_id' => '407254666900930563'])->first()`

Comment: could even try ->toSql() instead of ->first(), to verify the query is what you expect

Comment: @Ballard Yep, tried adjusting the syntax.  Also did use `->dd()` to fetch the original SQL to run in the instance itself

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE servers`

Comment: what if you try ```->where('platform_server_id', 407254666900930563)``` instead of ```->where('platform_server_id', "407254666900930563")```?

Comment: @Musa It doesn't matter whether it's a string or an int

Comment: Can you temporarily edit (or create a fake entry for testing) value of platform_server_id from ```407254666900930563``` to something smaller like ```123456``` and see if ```->toSql()``` returns a relevant request? Having ```893xxx``` instead of ```4072xxx``` looks like a type casting problem to me.

Comment: It's not, that's testing a different entity in the same data set.  I'm deleting that comment

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but is the `$table` property correctly set on your `Server` model? I assume so. Also, what result do you get when you use the `DB` facade (`DB::table('guilds')->where...`)?

Comment: @Ben Make sure you are connecting to right database from code and where you test your raw sql query, also check there is no caps issue with your table names like one with small and one with caps (linux based). Table names in MySQL are file system entries, so they are case insensitive if the underlying file system is.Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 2 ways to try, in both cases I recommend you to use the where **array** syntax because is more flexible:

#### Model query

```php
Server::where([
  'platform_id'=> 1,
  'platform_server_id' => $serverId
])->first();
```

**Or more explicit "where"**

```php
Server::where([
  ['platform_id', '=', 1],
  ['platform_server_id', '=', $serverId]
)->first();
```

#### DB query builder

```php
// table 'servers' or 'guilds', as I see above
DB::table('guilds')->where([
  'platform_id'=> 1,
  'platform_server_id' => $serverId
])->first();
```

**Or more explicit "where"**

```php
// table 'servers' or 'guilds', as I see above
DB::table('guilds')->where([
  ['platform_id', '=', 1],
  ['platform_server_id', '=', $serverId]
])->first();
```

#### Extra suggestions

**Mysql changelog**

Here I found the [mysql 8.0.23 changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html) for you to check.

**Laravel Tinker** you can use the command `php artisan tinker`, that allows you to "write pure" code in the terminal and execute it, you can try the queries I mentioned above and also try other without refactoring your code.

Copy and paste this to try: `Server::where([['platform_id', '=', 1],['platform_server_id', '=', 407254666900930563])->first();`

Answer (score 0):

These don't look the same:

```
407254666900930563
```

Is `platform_server_id` a BIGINT or a VARCHAR?

Also, I see inconsistencies in quoting the value.

Here's a guess:  When Laravel runs the query without quotes, it sees a number, converts it to `DOUBLE`.  But a Double cannot hold more than about 16 significant digits.  You seem to need all 18.

Please use the real numbers -- BIGINT also has a limitation that these numbers are close to.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are other details that may be relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the original question with some more detail.  Whether it's a string or int doesn't change anything, only whether there's 2 conditions or 1.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago we had to add "doctrine/dbal" to our "require" list in composer.json to fix some strange stuff.  You could try that by running this:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the id and the query you use is confused.
The platform_server_id in the create table statement is bigint, but you try to compare with a string or as you mentioned integer:

```
`platform_server_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL

$serverId = '407254666900930563';
Server::where('platform_id', 1)
```

You can not compare these values directly without conversion as you see in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072468/7996624